# Introducing a paragraph with "that way"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

May I use "that way" at the beginning of a paragraph, referring to the idea which was mentioned in the previous paragraph?

For instance:

That way, it is possible to conclude that...

Comment: I might start a sentence in the same paragraph in this manner, but not a new paragraph.

Comment: And do you think I may use "on that account" at the beggining of a paragraph even if it is not not properly a cause-effect relationship? I can give some more context:                                            (Paragraph describing my personal profile). / On that account, I am a peaceful person

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst it is not grammatically wrong, I would not start a new paragpraph that way because 'that' almost always references something you mentioned prevoisly.